CAMetalDisplayLink does not work on separate thread
I am looking to implement CAMetalDisplayLink on a separate thread on a macOS application. I am basing my implementation on the following example project:
Achieving Smooth Frame Rates with Metal Display Link
This project allows you to configure whether a separate thread is used for rendering by setting RENDER_ON_MAIN_THREAD in GameConfig to 0. However, when I set it to use a separate thread nothing is rendered. Stepping through the code shows that a separate thread is created, but a CAMetalDisplayLinkUpdate is never received. Does anyone know why this does not work?

In runThread in GameView.m, change
[runLoop runMode:_mode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

to
[runLoop run];

I don't know why the original code doesn't work (although it does use a lot of CPU), but this fixes the animation and the workload can be seen to move from the main thread to a secondary thread.

Change
_mode = NSRunLoopCommonModes;

to
_mode = NSDefaultRunLoopMode;

Then I can get the animation running.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
